# ¿EF Como permitir borrado en cascada en relación multiple one-to-many?

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, code-first

Tengo varios modelos (Code First) con llaves foráneas al id de `AspNetUsers`, y lo que quiero es que cuando borre un usuario, que se borren las filas de las tablas que tienen llaves foráneas al id del usuario. 
Esta es la estructura de las relaciones: (Donde las flechas son relaciones one-to-many)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
aquí el builder:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<PostModel>().HasOne(p => p.User).WithMany(u => u.Posts).HasForeignKey(e => e.UsrRef).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<FollowModel>().HasOne(f => f.Post).WithMany(p => p.Followers).HasForeignKey(e => e.PostRef).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    builder.Entity<FollowModel>().HasOne(f => f.FkUser).WithMany(u => u.Following).HasForeignKey(e => e.UsrRef).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<CommentModel>().HasOne(c => c.Post).WithMany(p => p.Coments).HasForeignKey(e => e.PostRef).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    builder.Entity<CommentModel>().HasOne(c => c.User).WithMany(u => u.Comments).HasForeignKey(e => e.UserRef).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Los modelos:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FollowModel> Following { get; set; }
}
public class PostModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FkUser")]
    public string UsrRef { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser FkUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }     
    public ICollection<FollowModel> Followers { get; set; }
}
public class CommentModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PostModel Post { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    [Required]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaPublicado { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Post")]
    public string PostRef { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserRef { get; set; }
}
public class FollowModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PostModel Post { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser FkUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FkUser")]
    public string UsrRef { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Post")]
    public string PostRef { get; set; }
}
```

El problema es que cuando hago el update-database me sale el siguiente error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Comments_AspNetUsers_UserRef' on table 'Comments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Acaso la lógica de relaciones que quiero aplicar no es permitida? hay alguna otra forma de hacer que cuando se borre un usuario, que se borre también los posts, comentarios, y following que este usuario hizo? o si el usuario quiere borrar x post, que se borren los comentarios de ese post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En las relaciones one-to-many por defecto se aplica delete on cascade si no especificas nada https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete.

El problema parece estar en el modelo que has creado. Tienes una relación en los comentarios respecto a los usuarios que no debería existir, ya que como te dice el error va a crear una relacción circular.

Los comentarios pertenecen a un post, que a su vez pertenece a un usuario. Deberías eliminar la relación entre comentarios y usuario (puedes sacar esos datos fácilmente sacando todos los posts de un usuario y luego todos los comentarios de esos posts). Si dejas las 2 relaciones al cargar usuarios los comentarios se cargan tanto en los posts como en los usuarios y eso crea un bucle.

Espero haberte ayudado,

Un saludo

Comment: Exactamente por lo que puede eliminar las relaciones user=>follows y user=>comments ya que mediante post puede acceder al usuario o viceversa desde post acceder a comentarios o seguidores de ese usuario

Comment: pero en CommentModel y FollowModel tengo un "public ApplicationUser User {get;set}", ¿con poner eso no se crea la llave foránea automáticamente? o lo puedo hacer con un "public string IdUsuario {get;set}" para que no cree la relación?

Comment: Para que necesitas añadir ahí la referencia al usuario? Piensa que un comentario siempre pertenece a un post, tendría sentido si hubiera comentarios sin post pero parece que cada comentario es relativo a un post. Efectivamente al añadir ese campo se crea una clave extranjera pero estas creando una referencia circular en las propiedades de navegación ya que Un usuario tiene posts, que tiene comentarios, que a su vez es de un usuario, que tiene posts, que a su vez tiene comentarios, que pertenecen a un usuario... Y así eternamente.